# Strip plus sign from end of number

Tags: php

I seem to be having trouble removing the plus sign from the end of a number.

I have a file which contains stock levels.  When the stock is over 20 they use 20+.

This does not seem to work.

```
    case 'MTA' :
      if (isset($line[0])) {

        $stock = ($line[15] == '20+') ? 20 : $line[15];
        }

        $rows[] = array('sku' => $line[0], 'stock' => $stock);
      }
      break;
```

I've also tried the following lines with no luck:

```
        if ($line[15] == '20+') {
          $line[15] = (int)20;

        $stock = (int)str_replace('20+', '20', $line[15]);

        $stock = str_replace('+', '', $line[15]);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the result of what you have tried? error? wrong value?

Comment: Could also use `urldecode($line[0])`. The `+` will be changed to a blank space - if there is one at all.

Comment: swdev, this is for a custom drupal module someone made for me a few years ago.  It's worked great until I picked up a new distributor who uses the 20+ format in their stock feeds.  The result is that the file gets partially parsed.  My skill with this is limited and I'm unable to debug much more.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
$stock = rtrim($line[15],"+");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rtrim`,`substr_replace`,`substr`

As per your example, `substr_replace` it can be written as follows

```
$line[15]= '20+';
$stock=substr_replace($line[15] ,"",-1);
echo $stock;
```

Using `substr`

```
$line[15]= '20+';
$stock=substr($line[15], 0, -1);
echo $stock;
```

Using `rtrim`

```
$line[15]= '20+';
$stock=rtrim($line[15], "+");
echo $stock;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$line[15]= '20+';
$stock = intval($line[15]);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.